# mysql table won't update when using php UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML page for updating a mysql table, and when the user is finished modifying it clicks a "submit" button at the bottom of the page, named 'valider'. I use POST method and the action leads to a php page with the UPDATE request but it won't update. I've tried putting the values from the previous page into variables before using them in the request but it still won't work. Here is the php code:

```
<?php
include_once("connexionMysql.php");
    if(isset($_POST['valider'])){
        $titreIci=$_POST["titre"];
        $idIci=$_POST["id"];
        $envoie= "UPDATE AY_albums SET titre='$titreIci' WHERE id='".$idIci."'";
    }

    header("Location: pageDaccueilAdmin.php");
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at these tutorials to learn how to communicate with your database via PHP: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEbKji_pSZM

Comment: Is your connection with DB is ok?

Comment: Okay will take a look Tom. And yes DB connection definitely works.

Comment: check for any typo, what I do is to copy the string of the query in the error_log and try to run that script directly in the database just to be sure if the query is well. Also, Where is your error handling? Are you getting any error in your logs?

Comment: $envoie is a STRING. You aren't actually executing it. Did you just leave that line of code out?

Comment: as of now I only have error handling in the page used to connect to the database which I included on every page. 

$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Comment: No that was all my code. Oh okay then I'm missing the execution!

Answer (score 1):

**CAREFUL** !! You have a BIG mistake in you code: you don't control the $idIci parameter!! so it is highly vulnerable about SQL injection attacks!! Anyone can wipe you database or deface you website...

Firstly, I suggest to control $idIci:

```
$idIci = $_POST['id']
if (!is_numeric($idIci))
{
    echo "Bad parameter!!";
    exit;
}
```

Or use PDO->bindParam() method... And where do you execute the query?

Comment: But the id is by definition numeric in the database, it is the primary key on auto_increment in the table in mysql db so it has to be numeric.

Comment: You don't have to submit numeric $_POST parameters... If an attacker (it can be easily done) sends to your server a request with ID at `1 OR 1 = 1` he just set all `titres` to $titreIci, for example... 
Because your request will be `UPDATE AY_albums SET titre='$titreIci' WHERE id=1 OR 1 = 1`...

Answer (score 1):

The "id" must be an **int** in your database and you are casting it as string this may cause issue also check your config file:
remove the header redirection to see if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should send `$invoie` variable to some function which send it to database server. Like `PDO::query($invoie);`

Answer (score 0):

Check `var_dump($_POST);` and see what data you have before SQL update line. You probably sent the wrong data. Also, use `$idIci = (int) $_POST["id"];` because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown in the question is simply assigning a string value to a variable.

That's all it's doing.

There's no execution of a SQL statement.

The contents of that variable are *not* getting sent to the database to be executed as a SQL statement. That's not happening, no matter *how much* you make the string *look like* a SQL statement. It's not going to be executed as a SQL statement unless your code makes that happen.

And fair warning... when the code *does* send that string to the database as a SQL statement, the code is going to be vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

Comment: Do I just need to add in a query in order to execute? Ex: `$updateIci=mysql_query($envoie);`

Comment: ACCCKKK.  The mysql_ interface functions are *deprecated*, and finally(!) removed (in PHP 7).  Use mysqli or PDO. For the love of all that is good and beautiful in this world... either use prepared statements with bind placeholders, or at least *properly escape* values that incorporated into the text of a SQL statement.